# APC configuration not getting loaded by PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apc

for some reason my php installation refuses to load the config for the APC Op-Cache.  But looking at phpinfo() every other config file in this directory is getting loaded.  Permissions seem ok.  below is a look at the directories and the config file itself. And i can confirm that apcu.so exists in the extensions directory as it should.  Any ideas here? im stumped.

```
root@friends:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d# ls -l
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    32 Apr  7  2014 05-opcache.ini -> ../../mods-available/opcache.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    28 Apr  7  2014 10-pdo.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    29 Aug  6 13:45 20-apcu.ini -> ../../mods-available/apcu.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    29 Apr  9  2014 20-curl.ini -> ../../mods-available/curl.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    27 Aug  6  2014 20-gd.ini -> ../../mods-available/gd.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    29 Apr  8  2014 20-json.ini -> ../../mods-available/json.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    31 Aug  6  2014 20-mcrypt.ini -> ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Feb  2  2015 20-memcached.ini -> ../../mods-available/memcached.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    30 Aug  6  2014 20-mssql.ini -> ../../mods-available/mssql.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    31 Apr  7  2014 20-mysqli.ini -> ../../mods-available/mysqli.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    30 Apr  7  2014 20-mysql.ini -> ../../mods-available/mysql.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Aug  6  2014 20-pdo_dblib.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo_dblib.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Apr  7  2014 20-pdo_mysql.ini -> ../../mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    33 Apr  7  2014 20-readline.ini -> ../../mods-available/readline.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22661 Apr 22 15:11 newrelic.ini
root@friends:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d# ls -l ../../mods-available/
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 119 Aug  6 13:47 apcu.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68 Apr  3  2014 curl.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  64 Jul  7  2014 gd.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  68 Aug  8  2013 json.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58 Aug  6  2014 mcrypt.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  70 Dec 19  2012 memcached.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  71 Jul  7  2014 mssql.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  71 Apr  3  2014 mysqli.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  70 Apr  3  2014 mysql.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  83 May  2  2014 opcache.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75 Jul  7  2014 pdo_dblib.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  66 Apr  3  2014 pdo.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  74 Apr  3  2014 pdo_mysql.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  76 Apr  3  2014 readline.ini
root@friends:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d# cat ../../mods-available/apcu.ini 
extension=apcu.so

apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=128M
apc.ttl=3600
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.max_file_size=1M
```